# BuildFire LocalStorage Not Saving Between Admin and Widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, local-storage, buildfire

I am having issue in BuildFire that works on my local computer but fails in production when the plugin is uploaded.

In my plug-in, I am having the user enter and save values to the buildfire local storage as such in my Content.js:

```
function saveCredentionals (){

    buildfire.localStorage.setItem("bw_organizer_id", organizer_id, (error) => {
      if (error) return console.error("something went wrong!", error);
      console.log("All is well, data saved and other plugins can now access it");
    });

    buildfire.localStorage.setItem("bw_access_token", access_token, (error) => {
      if (error) return console.error("something went wrong!", error);
      console.log("All is well, data saved and other plugins can now access it");
    });

  }
```

The files save correctly and values can be retrieved in the Content.js, even when page reloads. Next I try to retrieve the values in Widget.js as such:

```
Promise.all([
        buildfire.localStorage.getItem("bw_organizer_id"),
        buildfire.localStorage.getItem("bw_access_token"),
      ]).then(items => {

        let has_organizer_token = false;

        let has_access_token = false;

        if (items[0]) {
          has_organizer_token = true;
        }

        if (items[1]) {
          has_access_token = true;
        }

        if (has_access_token && has_access_token) {
          displayVideoPage(items[0], items[1]);
        } else {
          setMainContent(<div>Organizer ID and access token required.</div>);
        }


      });
```

This works on my local computer but fails to retrieve the value when I publish my plugin and run it on the app.buildfire.com . The items from the Promise are both null on production in my Widget.js.

Any thoughts on why this is happenings? The code is also open sourced here: https://github.com/BingeWave-Libraries/buildfire-livestream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is not meant to be shared between Control and Widget as the Widget should be able to run anywhere isolated from Control.

If you're looking to use localStorage as a shared communication you can check
[BuildFire Messaging](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/messaging-to-sync-your-control-to-widget/)

If you're looking to persist and share data you should look at:

- [BuildFire Datastore](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/datastore) (readonly for Widget)
- [BuildFire Public Data](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/public-data) (read and write for Widget)
- [BuildFire App Data](https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/app-data) (read and write for all app Widgets)

Comment: The datastore was the solution I ended up using.